Sum of ratio of gamma functions
I needed to solve the following expression:
$$
\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-a)}, \hspace{5mm} x,a,b \in \mathbb{N} .
$$
Now, I tried to find an alternative expression for it by myself, but I got stucked.
Then I tried with Wolfram Alpha, and I get an alternative expression. So it should not be too complicated to understand why this works, but I still do not manage to understand that.
The result from Wolfram Alpha is the following:
$$
\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-a)} = \frac{b-(a+1)}{a+1} \frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(b-a)}, 
$$
Hereby my attempt.
We try to show that the result from Wolfram Alpha is correct and proceed by induction in $a$.
Base case: S(a=1)
With $a=1$ we have on LHS:
$$
\sum_{x=2}^{b-1} \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-1)} = \sum_{x=2}^{b-1} \frac{(x-1)!}{(x-2)!} = \sum_{x=2}^{b-1} (x-1) = \sum_{x=1}^{b-2} x = \frac{ (b-2)(b-2+1)}{2} =  \frac{ (b-2)(b-1)}{2},
$$
where the penultimate equality follows from the Gauss Formula.
On the RHS we have:
$$
\frac{(b-2)}{2}(b-1),
$$
and so $S(a=1)$ is verified.
Induction step: from S(a+1)
We want to show that given $S(a)$ it follows $S(a+1)$.
For $S(a+1)$ we have on LHS:
$$
\sum_{x=a+2}^{b-1} \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-a-1)} \\
= \sum_{x=a+2}^{b-1} \frac{(x-1)!}{(x-a-2)!}  \\
= \sum_{x=a+2}^{b-1} \left[(x-1)  \cdots  (x-a-1) \right] \\
= \left\{ \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} \left[(x-1)  \cdots  (x-a-1) \right] \right\} + a (a-1) (a-2) \cdots (a+1 - a - 1) \\
= \left\{ \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} \left[(x-1)  \cdots  (x-a-1) \right] \right\} + 0 \\
= \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} (x-1)  \cdots  (x-a-1) \\
= \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} (x-1)  \cdots  (x-a)  (x-a-1) \\
= \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} (x-1)  \cdots  (x-a)  x -   \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} (x-1)  \cdots  (x-a) a   - \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} (x-1)  \cdots  (x-a)  .
$$
Now, we know from $S(a)$ that the second and third expression look like:
$$
- \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} (x-1)  \cdots  (x-a) a = - a \cdot \frac{b-(a+1)}{a+1} \frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(b-a)}
$$
$$
- \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} (x-1)  \cdots  (x-a)  =  - \frac{b-(a+1)}{a+1} \frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(b-a)}
$$
So second and third term together give:
$$
- (a+1) \frac{b-(a+1)}{a+1} \frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(b-a)}
$$
From here I got stucked and do not know how to proceed forward, as I cannot manipulate further the first of the three terms above.
If the result from Wolfram Alpha is correct, then we should be able to show that:
$$
\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} (x-1)  \cdots  (x-a)  x  = \frac{b}{a+2}\frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(b-a-1)}
$$
and from this the statement would follow. But I was not able to show this and have been sitting many hours on this: I tried with modification of Faulhaber's formula but it did not work.
Could anybody help me or provide a hint for that?
Thank you in advance.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1}{\Gamma(x)\over\Gamma(x-a)}&=\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1}{(x-1)!\over(x-a-1)!}\\&=a!\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1}{x-1\choose a}\\&=a!\left({a\choose a}+{a+1\choose a}+{a+2\choose a}+\cdots+{b-2\choose a}\right)\\&=a!\left({a+1\choose a+1}+{a+1\choose a}+{a+2\choose a}+\cdots+{b-2\choose a}\right)\\&=a!\left({a+2\choose a+1}+{a+2\choose a}+\cdots+{b-2\choose a}\right)\\&=a!\left({a+3\choose a+1}+\cdots+{b-2\choose a}\right)=a!{b-1\choose a+1}\\&={a!(b-1)!\over(a+1)!(b-a-2)!}={b-a-1\over a+1} {(b-1)!\over (b-a-1)!}\\&={b-a-1\over a+1} {\Gamma(b)\over \Gamma(b-a)}\end{align}
$$
For natural numbers $\Gamma(x)=(x-1)!$
And on the 4th,5th and 6th line we use pascal's identity$$
{a\choose b}+{a\choose b+1} = {a+1\choose b+1}
$$

Thank you! Beautiful!  I think you have a typo on the fifth line:  the first term inside the parenthesis is  ( a+2   a+1 ) and not ( a+2   a) , but it is clear anyway how it works. Thank you again

oh ye thanks mb fixed it

That calculation is known as the “Hockey-Stick identity”.

Thank you Martin!

There is an identity:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{k+n}{n} = \binom{n+m+1}{n+1} $$
which can be used in the following way.
$$ S = \sum_{k=a+1}^{b-1} \frac{\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(k-a)} = \sum_{k=0}^{b-a-2} \frac{\Gamma(k+a+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)} = a! \, \sum_{k=0}^{b-a-2} \binom{k+a}{a} = \frac{(b-1)!}{(a+1) \, (b-a-2)!}. $$
Note this is valid for $a \neq -1$ and conditions on $b$.
For ref:
Using
$$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \, \int_{C} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{k+1}} \, dz $$
then
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{k+n}{n} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \, \int_{C} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}} \, \sum_{k=0}^{m} (1+z)^k \, dz \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \, \int_{C} \frac{(1+z)^n \, ((1+z)^{m+1} - 1)}{z^{n+2}} \, dz \\
&= \binom{n+m+1}{n+1} - \binom{n}{n+1} = \binom{n+m+1}{n+1}.  
\end{align}

Thank you for this! Nice!
